# Which statistical test to use for percentage data?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, percentage

I am struggling to determine which test to use to compare the percentage data derived from continuous data. I am studying specific sleep characteristics in the context of depression. I have a population of **n = 717** individuals, out of which **n = 74** suffer from depression. I would like to compare the percentage of sleep time spent in one particular stage (N3) between depressed and non-depressed individuals.

The variable of interest is calculated as the duration of sleep spent in the N3 stage (in minutes) divided by the total sleep time (in minutes) and is not normally distributed.

|  | Not Depressed (n = 643) | Depressed (n = 74) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| % N3 sleep | 18.9 | 21.1 |

How can I test for a difference between the two groups? I am aware that questions about percentage comparisons have been asked in multiple threads, but they often refer to population proportions that do not correspond to my problem.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: "they often refer to population proportions that do not correspond to my problem". What do you mean?

Comment: Welcome.  

I agree with @ocram, what do you mean?   The threads are usually about tests, which are about how to infer from a sample to a population. That seems to me exactly what you are asking.

Comment: @ocram Thank you for the quick answer. Sorry if my question was not clear. What I meant is that I saw a lot of different posts in which the percentage data were derived from frequency counts (which can often be represented with a contingency table). In these cases, z or chi-squared tests are often advised. In my case, my percentage is obtained from the ratio of two continuous variables. Therefore I am wondering which test to apply as it seems to be a pretty different case. Can I treat it as a continuous variable ?